# Assign and/or manipulate incoming variables (string) from external program in bash

Tags: bash

I have an external program which hands me a bunch of information via stdin ($1) to my script.

I get a line like the following:

```
session number="2018/06/20-234",data name="XTRDF_SLSLWX3_FSLO",data group="Testing",status="Error",data type="0"
```

Now I want to use this line split into single variables.

I thought about two ways until now:

```
INPUT='session number="2018/06/20-234",data name="XTRDF_SLSLWX3_FSLO",data group="Testing",status="Error",data type="0"'
echo "$INPUT" | tr ',' '\n' | tr ' ' '_' > vars.tmp
set vars.tmp
```

This will do the job until I have a data_name variable with a space in it, my trim command will automatically change it to _ and my assigned variable is no longer correct in upcoming checks.

So I thought about loading the input into a array and do some pattern substitution on the array to delete everything until and including the = and do some variable assignments afterwards

```
INPUT='session number="2018/06/20-234",data name="XTRDF_SLSLWX3_FSLO",data group="Testing",status="Error",data type="0"'
IFS=',' read -r -a array <<< "$INPUT"
array=("${array[@]/#*=/}")
session_number="${array[0]}"
data_name="${array[1]}"
....
```

But now I have a strange behaviour cutting the input if there is a = somewhere in the data name or data group and I have no idea if this is the way to do it. I'm pretty sure there should be no = in the data name or data group field compared to a space but you never know...

How could I do this?

Comment: FYI, all-caps names are by convention used for variables meaningful to the operating system or shell, whereas names with at least one lower-case character are guaranteed not to modify the operation of POSIX-specified tools; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that a shell variable whose name overlaps with a preexisting environment variable will automatically be exported and overwrite the latter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simple Case: No Commas Within Strings

If you don't need to worry about commas or literal quotes inside the quoted data, the following handles the case you asked about (stray `=`s within the data) sanely:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: Requires bash 4.0 or newer" >&2; exit 1;; esac

input='session number="2018/06/20-234",data name="XTRDF_SLSLWX3_FSLO",data group="Testing",status="Error",data type="0"'
declare -A data=( )
IFS=, read -r -a pieces <<<"$input"
for piece in "${pieces[@]}"; do
  key=${piece%%=*}   # delete everything past the *first* "=", ignoring later ones
  value=${piece#*=}  # delete everything before the *first* "=", ignoring later ones
  value=${value#'"'} # remove leading quote
  value=${value%'"'} # remove trailing quote
  data[$key]=$value
done
declare -p data
```

...results in (whitespace added for readability, otherwise literal output):

```
declare -A data=(
  ["data type"]="0"
  [status]="Error"
  ["data group"]="Testing"
  ["data name"]="XTRDF_SLSLWX3_FSLO"
  ["session number"]="2018/06/20-234"
)
```

---

#### Handling Commas Inside Quotes

Now, let's say you *do* need to worry about commas inside your quotes! Consider the following input:

```
input='session number="123",error="Unknown, please try again"'
```

Now, if we try to split on commas without considering their position, we'll have `error="Unknown` and have `please try again` as a stray value.

To solve this, we can use GNU awk with the FPAT feature.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: Requires bash 4.0 or newer" >&2; exit 1;; esac

input='session number="123",error="Unknown, please try again"'

# Why do so many awk people try to write one-liners? Isn't this more readable?
awk_script='
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "[^=,]+=(([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\"))"
}

{
    printf("%s\0", NF)
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        printf("%s\0", $i)
    }
}
'

while :; do
  IFS= read -r -d '' num_fields || break
  declare -A data=( )
  for ((i=0; i<num_fields; i++)); do
    IFS= read -r -d '' piece || break
    key=${piece%%=*}
    value=${piece#*=}
    value=${value#'"'}
    value=${value%'"'}
    data[$key]=$value
  done
  declare -p data # maybe invoke a callback here, before going on to the next line
done < <(gawk "$awk_script" <<<"$input")
```

...whereafter output is properly:

```
declare -A data=(["session number"]="123" [error]="Unknown, please try again" )
```